# Staggered/Delayed Execution in Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I want to send to a server a series of socket requests/messages, but instead of doing it *exactly* at once, I want to have a series of functions 'firing' at random times, but often conflicting, to my server, but from one file. Is there a better way of doing this? Trying to 'flex' my routers multiplexing capabilities by testing it with simulated real time heavy traffic.

```
import multiprocessing 
import socket
import time

def send(num):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4837))
    s.sendall(b'Hello World %s' %num)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print('Received',repr(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=send, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Comment: In `send`, add a while loop and randomly wait some time between each connect/send/close iteration.

Comment: Is this simply straightforward load testing?  What do you expect as a saturation point for your router?  I fear that Python's interpreter isn't nearly fast enough to do the job.

Comment: Do you have a multi-processing core?  If not, your `multiprocessing` utility will be sequenced.

Comment: What sort of distribution do you want for the firing?  Poisson?